# Generate a Column that depends on the previous value of that column scala/python

Tags: python, pandas, scala

I need to generate a column that depends on the previous value of that column. The formula would be something like this:

*active customers t = actives customers in t-1 + hires in t - cancelations in t*

The data set I have has the new hirings and cancelation column and the *cumulative active policies* is my desired output.

[image]

Both scala or python alternatives are welcome!
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959703/calculate-value-based-on-value-from-same-column-of-the-previous-row-in-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem which seems of a cummulative nature with the function `.cumsum()`:

```
df['active customers t'] = (df['New Hirings'] - df['Cancelation']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   New Hirings  Cancelations  Cumulative Active Customers
0            1             1                            0
1            1             0                            1
2            2             0                            3
3            2             0                            5
4            5             1                            9
5            0             1                            8
6            7             0                           15
7            2             3                           14
8            0             2                           12
9            2             1                           13
```

Also, for future issues, please try to post your data as a text and not a picture!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I know how to generate a column based on other columns, what I don't know how to do is to reference the previous value of that same column! I have trouble using the previous value of a column to generate the next value of that same column.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't read the question throughoutly. You can use `.shift()` to shift to the previous value. Let me edit my answer in a minute. Also, could you please add an example output? Gracias!

Comment: Yes! My inputs are the columns new hiring and cancelations that are shown in the picture. I need to generate the column "cumulative active customers" that is shown on the picture. The calculation would be: new hirings t - cancelations in t + cumulative active customers in t-1. Does this make sense?

Comment: The calculation can be further simplified with cumulative values, like in the example I show. Do let me know if this does not work or you would like to discuss it any further, otherwise feel free to accept my answer!